# Could not find rake-11.3.0 on deployment (Capistrano Nginx Passenger)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, passenger, rvm-capistrano

- Recently updated an old web app to Rails 4.2.7.1 and Ruby 2.3.1 (It was working with Rails 3 and Ruby 1.9).
- App running on an nginx-pasenger server on production with rvm.
- Updated RVM and ruby in production, and set new ruby version as
  default.
- Deployed with Capistrano.

The app is not working, from the nginx log:

```
[ 2016-12-01 07:00:34.0368 1509/7fbcbf7fe700 agents/HelperAgent/RequestHandler.h:2306 ]: [Client 20] Cannot checkout session because a spawning$
App 6899 stdout:
App 6899 stdout:
[ 2016-12-01 07:01:13.2625 1509/7fbccdf3b700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:287 ]: Could not spawn process for application /home/deploy/porinstinto/c$
  Error ID: 9864a1e8
  Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-NDJl0Z.html
  Message from application: <p>It looks like Bundler could not find a gem. Maybe you didn't install all the gems that this application needs. T$

  <pre class="commands">bundle install</pre>

<p>If that didn't work, then the problem is probably caused by your application being run under a different environment than it's supposed to. $

<ol>
  <li>Is this app supposed to be run as the <code>deploy</code> user?</li>
  <li>Is this app being run on the correct Ruby interpreter? Below you will
      see which Ruby interpreter Phusion Passenger attempted to use.</li>
  <li>Please check whether the correct RVM gemset is being used.</li>
  <li>Sometimes, RVM gemsets may be broken.
      <a href="https://github.com/phusion/passenger/wiki/Resetting-RVM-gemsets">Try resetting them.</a></li>
</ol>

<p>-------- The exception is as follows: -------</p>
Could not find rake-11.3.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
<pre>  /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize&#39;
  /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `map!&#39;
  /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize&#39;
  /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:132:in `specs&#39;
  /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:177:in `specs_for&#39;
  /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:166:in `requested_specs&#39;
  /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs&#39;
  /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup&#39;
  /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler.rb:121:in `setup&#39;
  /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17:in `&lt;top (required)&gt;&#39;
  /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require&#39;
  /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require&#39;
  /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require&#39;
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:263:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code&#39;
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:366:in `running_bundler&#39;
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:261:in `run_load_path_setup_code&#39;
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:100:in `preload_app&#39;
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:158:in `&lt;module:App&gt;&#39;
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `&lt;module:PhusionPassenger&gt;&#39;
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `&lt;main&gt;&#39;</pre>

[ 2016-12-01 07:01:13.2791 1509/7fbcbf7fe700 agents/HelperAgent/RequestHandler.h:2306 ]: [Client 20] Cannot checkout session because a spawning$
```

**UPDATE**

- Running "Bundle" in production server I can see that rake-11.3.0 is installed.
- Readed suggested [link](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/wiki/Resetting-RVM-gemsets) about gemsets.
- It seems that all gems are instaled in gemset 2.3.1@default
- Seems also, reading error log, that passenger is using ruby-2.1.3@global gemset, wich has no proper gems installed.

  Now, I have to change passenger gemset config to use correct "default" gemset. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

try with  :

```
bundle exec rake 'option'
```

Comment: on production server?

Comment: Have I to run your previous sugerence `bundle exec rake rake-command` on production server or on my own development machine?

Comment: bundle exec use if any gem is mismatch, like any migration fails due to rake gem version mismatch so we can use bundle exec rake db:migrate

Comment: Ok, sorry, I understood now. This error is produced when trying to access to the web page, so is not associated to any particular rake task.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved, it was a problem on Nginx-passenger config.

nginx.conf file was pointing to ruby 2.1.3 (a prev version of ruby I used) so I simply replaced this line with:

```
passenger_ruby /home/deploy/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.3.1/ruby;
```